# Determine compression % of gzip file?

Tags: linux, gzip

Is there an easy way to determine the compression % of a `.gz` file?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/139253/what-is-the-maxiumum-compression-ratio-for-gzip-algorythm

Comment: Ah crap didnt mean to post this on SF. Migrate or close if necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

from `man gzip`:

-l, --list
This option displays information about the file's compressed and uncompressed size, ratio, uncompressed name.  With the -v option, it also displays the compression method, CRC, date and time embedded in the file.